# Multi theme support for Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

What will be a better approach to display labels in a web app based on a user.

For ex: We have User groups A and B. And labels and headers differ between groups. There will be no changes in the layout and only text differs.

I was looking at [Rails themes](https://github.com/chamnap/themes_on_rails_example). However looks like it works well for assets and themes.

Looking for suggestions here. App is on Rails 4.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you may use decorator pattern with gem [draper](https://github.com/drapergem/draper)

Implementation will look something like this:

```
# app/decorators/group_decorator.rb
class GroupDecorator < Draper::Decorator
  def name
  end
end

# app/decorators/group_one_decorator.rb
class GroupOneDecorator < GroupDecorator
  def name
    'group one specific message'
  end
end

# app/decorators/group_one_decorator.rb
class GroupTwoDecorator < GroupDecorator
  def name
    'group two specific message'
  end
end
```

Then wherever you can just call `decorate` on `group`

```
user.group.decorate.name
```

or

```
GroupOneDecorator.new(user.group).name
```